# Error during SonarQube Scanner execution from Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I get the following error when I try to execute SonarQube Scanner as a part of Jenkins build:

```
ERROR: SonarQube server [http://<hostname>:9000] can not be reached

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: Total time: 0.242s

INFO: Final Memory: 5M/483M

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution

org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube

at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)

at 
... 8 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Status returned by
 url [http://<hostname>:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [404]

at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:115)

at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getBootstrapIndex(Jars.java:96)

... 12 more

ERROR:
```

I can access the following URL from my Jenkins host: http://:9000/sonar/ . When I try to execute this:

```
wget http://<hostname>:9000/batch/index
```

I get the same 404 http error in response. I have no idea from where this URL postfix **/batch/index** comes from. Web search did not give any clues for this.

My Sonar version is 6.0. My Jenkins Sonar Scanner plugin version is 2.6.1.

Used JVM:

java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2):

What is your the setting for sonar's web context (`sonar.web.context`) on your sonar server? It would be inside of `sonar.properties`. By default both the Jenkins plugin and the sonar server configuration set it to root:

```
'http://<hostname>:9000/'
```

The first thing I would do is to make sure those are matching in the sonar configuration and the jenkins plugin configuration.

I've seen tutorials that tell you to use `/sonar` or something similar. In that case, the jenkins plugin would need to be set to `/sonar` as well, like:

```
'http://<hostname>:9000/sonar'
```